# QTableWidget Drag&Drop cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4

Как в переопределенном методе "dropEvent" определить в какую ячейку перетаскивается объект, так же необходимо знать из какой ячейки этот объект перетаскивается, и необходимо получить сам объект (QTableWidgetItem).
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом:

```
void MyClass::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event){
    // Получаем объект который лежит в ячейке куда перемещаем 
    QTableWidgetItem *target = itemAt(event->pos());

    /* тут лучше сохранить данные из target иначе после следующего оператора они потеряются */

    // Выполняем стандартное перемещение
    QTableWidget::dropEvent(event);

    //Получили перемещенный объект 
    QTableWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->pos());
}
```